# Issue with referential integrity one to many drop down

Tags: ms-access, combobox, one-to-many, referential-integrity

Issue with Referential Integrity, one to many form and drop down. Keeps receiving message "cannot add a related record".

Trying to create a multiple form database that tracks one to many changes that
allow me to track changes to specific person in a database, and i keep getting an error whenever i try to save a form, because no related record exist, and i need on the drop down to see the full name. any help appreciated.

Tables Include

```
Persons          Fields Include PersonID FirstName, LastName, SSN
Characteristics  Fields Include CharacteristicsID PersonID Height, Weight
Contact          Fields ContactID PersonID Phone, Email
ChangeT          Fields ChangeID ContactID haracteristicsID PersonID
```

Forms Include

```
Person Records    
Characteristics - I have a drop down here that should give me the name and allow an update
```

Relationships Include

```
PersonT PersonID to ChangeT PersonID OnetoMany
ChangeT ChangeID to ContactT PersonID OnetoMany
ChangeT ChangeID to CharacteristicsT PersonID OnetoMany
```

It should save to the table with the personID and instead i get an error on the characteristics saying no related field available.

Comment: Why do you have Persons, Characteristics, and Contact as 3 tables? If you want an audit trail of changes to data, review http://allenbrowne.com/AppAudit.html

Comment: To analyze issue, would have to know properties of form and combobox - RecordSource, RowSource, ColumnCount, ColumnWidths, BoundColumn, ControlSource. Maybe should consider form/subform arrangement.